# "POST" method is not allowed in Python web page using Flask

Tags: python, post, flask, methods

I'm trying to make a form using this code.

```py
from flask import Flask,render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="Templates")

@app.route("/form", methods=["POST"])
def form():
    name = request.form.get("name")
    return render_template("form.html", name=name)

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

also use **form.html** code

```
{% extends "index.html" %}

{% block heading %}
Hello
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
Hi ! {{name}}
{% endblock %}
```

and this is layout file called **index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My WebSite</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>{% block heading %}{% endblock %}</h1>

        {% block body %}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
<html>
```

but it shows an error on my web page saying that the method is now allowed, taking a look to flask log shows the next information:

```
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Apr/2020 08:31:19] "GET /form HTTP/1
.1" 405 -
```

then, how can I solve this problem? Please help guys!!!

Comment: You've only defined `POST`, but you're doing a `GET` request (which is what your web browser does by default when you go to a URL). It's difficult to make a web browser do a POST request for you - I recommend a tool like Postman or Insomnia (a REST client) for testing anything other than GET. But then, `POST` should really only be used when you're giving data to a service - when you're just viewing things, it should be a `GET` request. Read up on REST design principles.

Comment: thanks bro !!! i've install "postman" and it's working